# Why does JPQL's "OR" operator narrow result set?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have three tables: "User", "Employee" and "Worker". "User" table has one-to-zero-or-one relationship with "Worker" and the same one-to-zero-or-one with "Employee". User entity bean has following mapping attributes:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
private Worker worker;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_employee", referencedColumnName = "id")
@OneToOne
private Employee idEmployee;
```

My aim is to get all "User" records which have one of this attributes filled (not null). I try to use the query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.idEmployee IS NOT NULL OR u.worker IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY u.login
```

I suppose to get 15 records, but I get only 6. I divided this query into two separate:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.idEmployee IS NOT NULL ORDER BY u.login;
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.worker IS NOT NULL ORDER BY u.login;
```

I get 9 and 6 records, respectively. Put together - required 15 records.
[image: screenshot of queries and result sets]

It looks like "OR" narrows the result set to only those records, which have worker field not null. Why does it work in such way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps if you actually look at the SQL invoked you'd understand it

Comment: When I perform the same JPQL with DataNucleus it does a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and hence gives the expected results ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worker association is mapped by a foreign key in the worker table. This means that using `u.worker` makes an inner join to the worker table, and the `is not null` is always true. The resulting SQL should look like this:

```
select u.* from user u, worker w where u.id = w.user_id and w.user_id is not null.
```

You need to use a left join to accept users having no worker:

```
select u from User u
left join u.worker w
left join u.employee e
where w is not null or e is not null
```

Comment: I don't understand why "OR" behaves in such way in my example, but your "inner join" example solved my problem, request returns exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: It's not "or", it's "where u. worker =", which generates a SQL inner join, restricting results to only users which have a non-null user_id.

Comment: "u.worker" will only generate an INNER JOIN if the JPA implementation doesn't bother analysing the full JPQL; some realise that LEFT OUTER is needed

Comment: @DataNucleus: if I read the spec correctly, such a "smart" JPA implementation (and I think I know which one you're thinking about) would be in violation of the spec, which says: "Path expression navigability is composed using “inner join” semantics"

Comment: Such an implementation passes all compliance tests for aforementioned specification, and by providing intelligent SQL generation provides the user with what they logically expect a query to generate when using an "OR" clause, that is, when there is an OR clause and one side composes a join then using left outer is the only logical option. Sure other implementation impose that thinking on a user, but then aren't they in the business of trying to help the user do their job ?

Answer (score 0):

i actually had similar problem recently, and it turns out i was using old version of eclipse link, where statements is null and is not null wasn't correctly executed if they were part of and/or statement.
If i remember fix for that was in eclipse link 2.2.0. if you are not using eclipse link, ignore my post.